# What does "Runs" means in Tensorboard Profile Page?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am profiling my deep model using TensorFlow profile plugin. After the profiling, I can see multiple folders under the `path-to-log-dir/plugins/profile/`. And from the Profile page, I can see there're multiple Runs options.

[image]

Why there're multiple "Runs"? How are they generated?

Answer (score 0):

These are multiple logs of runs. Each of which stored in the logs folder.

For example you can define a separate folder for each run using time like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

logdir = "logs/training/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logdir, 
                                                      histogram_freq = 1)
```

Each time you run the above code, a new folder will be created under `logs/training/`. Also you may get multiple folders in each run of the line where you passed the callback e.g. `model.fit(callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])`, which each of them belongs to a separate run (for example one will be created for training, and one for validation logs):

1. `logs/training/20210804-114159`
2. `logs/training/20210804-114211`

Then when you run tensorboard in parent folder:

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs/training
```

You can select each run you want to show profiled data.

Comment: I didn't run multiple times. I only run once, then it give me multiple folders under the `plugin/profile` not under your "training" folder.

Comment: Names are not important. I defined my own folder names. Don't care names. What is important is that, runs are different logs folders under your log directory. They may be for once running validation, and once running training (in one running model.fit()). There maybe exist from previous running or any other scenarios. what is important is that they are different logs for different runs, which you can track them by their name (name of run).